# How to convert a nested object into an array of group options (React hooks)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-hooks

I am a new dev and I am having trouble converting this nested object into an array of options with categories.

Response from API call:

```
{
    "category1": [
    {
        "categoryCode": "category1",
        "categoryLabel": "Vehicles",
        "code": "AAA",
        "label": "Car a"
    },
    {
        "categoryCode": "category1",
        "categoryLabel": "Vehicles",
        "code": "BBB",
        "label": "Car b"
    }
    ],
    "category2": [
    {
        "categoryCode": "category2",
        "categoryLabel": "Ship",
        "code": "CCC",
        "label": "Ship a"
    },
    {
        "categoryCode": "category2",
        "categoryLabel": "Ship",
        "code": "DDD",
        "label": "Ship b"
    },
    {
        "categoryCode": "category2",
        "categoryLabel": "Ship",
        "code": "EEE",
        "label": "Ship c"
    },
    ],
}
```

The output should be this:

```
options = [
    {
label: "Vehicles",
options: [
            { label: "Car a", value: "AAA"
            },
            { label: "Car b", value: "BBB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
label: "Ship",
options: [
            { label: "Ship a", value: "CCC"
            },
            { label: "Ship b", value: "DDD"
            },
            { label: "Ship c", value: "EEE"
            },
        ]
    },
];
```

Comment: Please consider using a triple-tick block code quote instead of this, which is quite hard to read.

Comment: or just indent with four spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the values of the object and map with getting some values from the first object of each group.

```js
const
    data = { category1: [{ categoryCode: "category1", categoryLabel: "Vehicles", code: "AAA", label: "Car a" }, { categoryCode: "category1", categoryLabel: "Vehicles", code: "BBB", label: "Car b" }], category2: [{ categoryCode: "category2", categoryLabel: "Ship", code: "CCC", label: "Ship a" }, { categoryCode: "category2", categoryLabel: "Ship", code: "DDD", label: "Ship b" }, { categoryCode: "category2", categoryLabel: "Ship", code: "EEE", label: "Ship c" }] },
    result = Object
        .values(data)
        .map(array => ({
            label: array[0].categoryLabel,
            options: array.map(({ label, code: value }) => ({ label, value }))
        }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```